# git remote branches listing

Tags: git

Is there any way I can use the GIT cli to figure out how many git branches are present at a remote repository?

It would be nice to see if someone unknowingly pushed a branch that I dont desire into the remote repository.

Comment: I'm new to git so I'll leave this here as a comment, but can't you use `git branch -a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git branch -r` will list all branches on all configured remotes. You may want to do a `git fetch --all` first to make sure it's up to date.

Comment: This will give you all the remote tracking branches on the local system. It will include any that may have been deleted on the remote but not pruned locally, and exclude any that exist on the remote but have not been tracked locally. Use @jszakmeister's answer to get the  current list of branches that exist on the remote.

Comment: @ellotheth I disagree -- `git branch -r` shows all remote branches whether I have tracked them or not. It doesn't correlate to what I have locally or not. It may not be up to date if a `git fetch` hasn't been run first. It's easy to verify (I just did).

Comment: @ellotheth I think the confusion is over the definition of `remote-tracking branches`. Search around for definitions of it, one reference that is pretty clear is: http://www.gitguys.com/topics/tracking-branches-and-remote-tracking-branches/ In git speak, `git branch -r` is a porcelain command to list remote branches while `git ls-remote` is a plumbing command that is more powerful/flexible but more complicated to use.

Comment: No, `branch -r` gives you remote tracking branches. When you clone a repo, you automatically start tracking all the remote branches. In that case, yes, `branch -r` gives you everything. If a branch is deleted off the remote and you don't prune your local repo, `branch -r` will give you the deleted branch. If you track only specific branches from a remote (`remote set-branches` or something similar), `branch -r` will give you just what you're tracking. You're right, it is [easy to verify](http://pastebin.com/16XwBqKc).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git ls-remote <url/to/remote/repo.git>` to git a listing of all references present in the remote repository.

Comment: git ls-remote gives me a list of branches like:

e7aa...d6c9  HEAD
3e68..b021  refs/heads/ABC-123-my-jira-first-branch
ad5e...c649   refs/heads/ABC-456-another-branch

and git branch -r gives me

origin/ABC-123-my-jira-first-branch
origin/ABC-456-another-branch

but NEITHER of these formats works with git pull <remote> <branch>

...
Where do I find the correct name of the remote branch to use with git pull?